# For a uniform random variable $U\in[0,1]$ , thinking of finding the law of $-\log U$ by calculating the distribution function using $P(U \leq t) = t$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let U be a uniform random variable defined on $[0,1]$

Notice that $-\log(U)$ is defined on $[0,+\infty]$

There are two ways to find the law of $-\log(U)$, I do get the method using the law of the unconscious statistician.

But for the method using the distribution function, 
we calculate the distribution function of $F(t)=P(-\log U \leq t)$
where 
$F(t) = 0$ for $t <0$ , and we calculate $F(t)$ only for $t \geq 0$. We use that the distribution function of $U$ is

$ \textbf{ P(U $\leq$ t) = t}$ for $t \in [0,1] $ to find that

$F(t) = P(\log \frac{1}{U} \leq t) = P(\frac{1}{U} \leq e^t) = P(U \leq e^{-t}) = 1- e^{-t} $

Which then we need to recognize the exponential distribution function of parameter 1.

My question is why is  $P(U \leq t) = t$ and how to think of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the definition of uniform distribution. Probability that $U$ takes values in an interval $(a,b) \subset (0,1)$ is the length of the interval $b-a$. Here we have $a=0$ and $b=t$.